# How can I pass data from my PyQt5 UI input to my python program?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

So I made my python program which is a basketball game simulator that takes input from the user in the terminal, and I wanted to add a UI to it so I am now trying to hook it up to PyQt5 and have a nice display for it. The thing is, when I launch my program, I want the program to wait for the user to type something in the lineEdit and click enter, then run the simulation using the user's input. But what ends up happening is once I launch the program, the UI opens and then the rest of the simulation instantly runs, so there is no time for the user to input anything in the lineEdit.

In my UI class, I have the code for the UI and then this is what I have for the lineEdit and the lineEdit enter button

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        #40 lines of code for the UI....
 
        self.enterButton.clicked.connect(self.enterPressed)

def enterPressed(self):
    userInput = self.lineEdit.text()
    self.lineEdit.clear()
    return userInput
```

And then here is the beginning of the code for the main program which needs the user input for the UI

```
year = int(input("Enter year between 1980-2022: "))

while year < 1980 and year > 2022:
    year = int(input("Invalid input, enter year between 1980-2022: "))
            
yearStandings = requests.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_" + str(year) + "_standings.html").text
```

Instead of asking the user for the input through the terminal, I want to assign the variable "year" the value that is put in the lineEdit. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also note that you are ***not*** expected to edit a pyuic generated file (nor mimic or merge its code), and you should follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
# IMPORTS

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def self(self, MainWindow):
         # 40 lines of code
         self.enterButton.clicked.connect(self.enterPressed)
    def enterPressed(self):
         year = int(self.lineEdit.text())
         if year<1980 or year>2022 :
            print("Invalid input, enter year between 1980-2022: ")
            return None
         global yearStandings
         yearStandings = requests.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_" + str(year) + "_standings.html").text

# And Remaining Code with pyuic5 code generated with -x argument
```

You can then close the GUI (if u want)
after storing the information in `yearStandings` Variable and print it in the terminal or whatever you want